# Scrolled distance from top in ng-perfect-scrolbar

Tags: angular, scroll, scrollbar

I want to subscribe to scroll event on ng-perfect-scrollbar to track the scrolled distance. Something like this:

```
<perfect-scrollbar (onScroll)='distanceFromTop => console.log(distanceFromTop )'>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</perfect-scrollbar>
```

What I have tried:
I added directive to the scrollbar and tried to get the native element and set onscroll to my function:

```
<perfect-scrollbar #mainScrollbar>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</perfect-scrollbar>

@ViewChild('mainScrollbar') private mainScrollbar: 
ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

ngAfterContentInit() {
   console.log(this.mainScrollbar.nativeElement);
   this.mainScrollbar.nativeElement.onscroll = e => console.log(e);
}
```

I'm getting the following messages in the console:

> undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

It's not necessary to use `@ViewChild` to answer my question, I just need a working example of logging the scroll distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other people who might be interested in an answer, after digging into the implementation I found a solution:

1) Get the reference to the component like in [demo app](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-perfect-scrollbar/tree/master/example)

`@ViewChild(PerfectScrollbarComponent) componentRef?: PerfectScrollbarComponent;`

2) Get a directive reference from the component reference:

`this.componentRef.directiveRef`

3) Now you can call position on the directive reference:

`console.log(this.componentRef.directiveRef.position(true));`

4) To get scrolled distance every time the user scrolls use directives like: (psScrollY) or (psScrollX) with callback function, which calls `this.componentRef.directiveRef.position(true)`